# SSLError ( certificate verify failed)

Tags: python, gradio

I'm trying to run simple gradio app with https:

```
import gradio as gr

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with gr.Blocks(theme=gr.themes.Glass()) as demo:
        testLabel = gr.Label(label="Just for test")

    demo.queue().launch(share=False,
                        debug=False,
                        server_name="0.0.0.0",
                        server_port=8432,
                        ssl_certfile="/home/user/cert.pem",
                        ssl_keyfile="/home/user/key.pem")
```

And I'm getting error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8432): Max retries exceeded with url: /startup-events (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1131)')))
```

I'm using the following versions:

```
gradio==3.28.0
gradio-client==0.1.4
```

How can I run this simple app with https ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you use a self-signed certificate?

The problem is that when you use a self-signed certificate, SSL verification fails.
You can disable verification by adding a `ssl_verify=False` parameter when launching.

```py
demo.queue().launch(share=False,
                        debug=False,
                        server_name="0.0.0.0",
                        server_port=8432,
                        ssl_certfile="/home/user/cert.pem",
                        ssl_keyfile="/home/user/key.pem",
                        ssl_verify=False
)
```